# Size limit for CNContact images

Tags: ios, swift, cncontact

I am fetching contacts in my iOS Application. I send the contacts' information to a remote server. The images are sent encoded in Base64.

I am afraid of a potential risk when images are too big. I want to know if Apple has clarified a max image size when retrieving them using [thumbnailImageData](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/contacts/cncontact/1402903-thumbnailimagedata) or [imageData](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/contacts/cncontact/1402968-imagedata).

I know I can process the image before send it to the remote in order to reduce its size, but **my goal right now is to know if there is a max size a contact's image can have**.